# How to add an object array property?

Tags: javascript

When reading the attribute `name`, put the `user3` of the attribute `user2` and the same attribute into an object attribute `name` equal to `a` value.

**I want to print it out：**

```
[
  {
    name: 'b',
    user1: 'haha',
  },
  {
    name: 'a',
    user2: 'apple',
    user3: 'xiaomi'
  }
]
```

**my code:**

```js
var data = [{
    name: 'b',
    user1: 'haha',
  },
  {
    name: 'a',
    user2: 'apple',
  },
  {
    name: 'a',
    user3: 'xiaomi'
  }
]

var arr = []

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  console.log(data[i].name)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code is first going to make known the same `name` fields and then will merge them.

```
var make_unique = function(xs, key) {
  // find same name fields
  let tmp_result =  xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
  // merge the same ones
  return Object.keys(tmp_result).map(item => {
     return tmp_result[item].reduce(function(rv, x) {
        return Object.assign(rv,x)
     }, {});
  })
};
```

To call it:

```
make_unique(data,'name')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use for loop to find same elements and assign one to the other then remove the found element from the array with splice method

```js
var data = [{
    name: 'b',
    user1: 'haha',
  },
  {
    name: 'a',
    user2: 'apple',
  },
  {
    name: 'a',
    user3: 'xiaomi'
  }
]

for (var i=0 ; i<data.length;i++){
  for(var j=i+1;j<data.length;j++){
    if(data[i].name===data[j].name){
      Object.assign(data[i],data[j])
      data.splice(j,1)
    }
  }
}
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) over the data to create an object with keys set to the name values, then return the [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) of that object:

```js
var data = [{ name: 'b', user1: 'haha' }, { name: 'a', user2: 'apple' }, { name: 'a', user3: 'xiaomi' }];

function groupByName(arr) {
  return Object.values(data.reduce((acc, c) => {
    const { name, ...rest } = c;
    acc[name] = acc[name] || {};
    acc[name] = { ...acc[name], name, ...rest };
    return acc;
  }, {}));
}

const output = groupByName(data);
console.log(output);
```